# Spring '13 Sandbox error with beta-package install

Tags: managed-package, beta-managed-package

I'm installing a beta package into a Spring '13 Sandbox org.

Previously we didn't have any issues with installing into this sandbox, but now I am getting an error, which our partner support has revealed to us is:

```
Object.CustomExternalIdField__c: duplicate value found: %3cunknown%3e duplicates value on record with id: %3cunknown%3e:
```

I've changed the name of my object/field for privacy sake, but this is the only reference we have to the object in our source code. Nothing changed about it between this and any previous packaged versions.

Any ideas?

Comment: after refreshing the sandbox this error is gone. still doesn't explain what happened. maybe a broken uninstall? I am going to leave this open incase anyone else comes across this issue and doesn't have the luxury of refreshing their sandbox

Comment: I am curious that after refreshing your Sandbox, are you still in Spring'13 or go back to the Winter'13?

Comment: I am still in Spring '13